# Saving & retrieving images on Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

On the process of trying Firebase, as a possible replacement to Parse.com (unfortunately to disappear), I have saved a PNG image online using the code below, in Swift.

```
    let fn = self.toolBox.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("M0-1.png")
    let im = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fn),
    dat = UIImagePNGRepresentation(im!),
    b64 = dat?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength),
    qs = ["string": b64!],
    r = diltRootRef.childByAppendingPath("zs"),
    us = ["img": qs]
    r.setValue(us)
```

The saving part seems to work, but how am I suppose to get back the image I saved? All I have tried so far failed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend retrieving images using `observeSingleEventOfType(:_)`, because it's a one-time read.

Once you have the string value synchronized, you can use an `NSData()` initializer, and then create an `UIImage`.

```
imageRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value) { (imageSnap: FDataSnapshot!) in
  let base64String = imageSnap.value as! String
  let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))    
  let image = UIImage(data: decodedData!)
}
```

[Check out this example repo on using base64 images in a UITableView.](https://github.com/davideast/iOS-Firebase-Pokedex)

Comment: There is both read and write swift code in the answer to this question [Swift2 retrieving images from Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644560/swift2-retrieving-images-from-firebase/34044446#34044446) and with David's answer change the read from observeEventType to observeSingleEventOfType

Comment: @Jay please mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done

Comment: See the duplicate question: it works. This snippet of code produces an error for me.

Comment: What's the error @thiagowfx? The other question uses a realtime observer which is not great for performance when downloading images.