# Firebase : Upload image or file from dashboard

Tags: upload, firebase, dashboard

I'm trying to find a good alternative at Parse.

**FireBase** seems to be good, but I can't find how to **upload image/file** from the dashboard like in Parse ?

Can we upload image/file from the firebase dashboard like in Parse ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above is an answer, it's does't provide a solution, so here's a bit more data.

Uploading/storing data in firebase is super simple and requires a minimal amount of code.

For images, encode the image as a string and store the string in firebase. Then to retrieve the image, retrieve the string and decode it.

You should be able to do both in about 12 lines of code (depending on platform).

There are several examples already published here, I like this one with Swift.

[Swift2 retrieving images from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33644560/swift2-retrieving-images-from-firebase/34044446#34044446)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

**No You Can Not** because **firebase** doesn't provide such type of feature.

Edit:

Ah! My old accepted answer got unaccepted because I gave straight answer :) Well OP didn't ask about programming way of solution so I assumed not to provide one.

There are couple of approaches to handle images with firebase, I usually upload images to `s3 bucket` and store `urls` in firebase. Again there is choice to implement above approach i.e. do all on server-side, do all on client-side or do with mix of client-side and server-side. But It is better to do `signaturing` on server to keep thing secure.

**Node-Cheat Available:**

For complete code, get working node-cheat at [github node-cheat aws](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/tree/master/aws), choose any folder and run `node file_name`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot upload directly, but you could use some opensource project out there that will make a simple dashboard for you to upload it easily like this [tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-firebase-storage-uploads-multi/)

[image]